# the surface area of the cream white colored surface wants to be calculated using integral

Tags: definite-integrals, 3d, area

I Want to calculate the area of the cream colored surface illustrated on the image below using integral. variables are $\beta$ and $\phi$ and constants are R and r 
[image: the surface area of the cream white colored surface wants to be calculated using $\beta$ and $\phi$ and Radius as variables]

Comment: You may assume the radius of the large sphere is 1, but then the result would still depend on how far up the hinged angle marked $\beta$ is located. [If that distance is $r<1$ then the part of the entire cap depends on $r$, and also the amount of the area sliced off by the hinged part.]

Comment: @coffeemath you are right it also depends on R, but we can assume R as a constant value. Actually R is indeed constant. my variables are $\phi$ and $\beta$. my problem is I can't define the finite segment to develop the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts.

I use spherical coordinates
\begin{align}
x&=R\sin\theta\cos\varphi\\
y&=R\sin\theta\sin\varphi\\
z&=R\cos\theta
\end{align}
where my $\theta$ corresponds to $\varphi$ in your image.
The unit versor normal to the plane inclined at an angle $\beta$ is
$$
\mathbf{n}=\cos\beta\,\mathbf{j}+\sin\beta\,\mathbf{k}
$$
so that the equation of the inclined plane (passing through $(0,0,h)$) is
$$
y\cos\beta+(z-h)\sin\beta=0
$$
Here $h$ is $R-r=R\cos\theta_0$, and $\theta_0$ is the maximum value of $\theta$ corresponding to the horizontal plane $z=R-r$.

The equation of the inclined plane in spherical coordinates becomes
$$
R\sin\theta\sin\varphi\cos\beta+(R\cos\theta-h)\sin\beta=0
$$
This is a contraint between $\theta$, $\varphi$, we can write
$$
\sin\varphi=-\frac{\cos\theta-\cos\theta_0}{\sin\theta}\tan\beta
$$
This sets a minimum value for $\sin\varphi$, except for the higher part of the surface, where the RHS of last eq. is lesser than $-1$, say for $0\leq\theta\leq\theta_1$.
Set, where meaningful,
$$
\varphi(\theta)=\arcsin\left(\frac{\cos\theta-\cos\theta_0}{\sin\theta}\tan\beta\right)
$$
so that we can write ($R^2\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\varphi$ is the surface element in spherical coordinates):
\begin{align}
S&=\int_Sd\sigma=\int_0^{\theta_1}d\theta\int_0^{2\pi}R^2\sin\theta\,d\varphi
  +\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_0}d\theta
  \int_{-\varphi(\theta)}^{\pi+\varphi(\theta)}R^2\sin\theta\,d\varphi\\
&=2\pi R^2(1-\cos\theta_1)
  +R^2\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_0}(\pi+2\varphi(\theta))\sin\theta\,d\theta
\end{align}
I cannot go further in calculating the last integral.

Comment: I am solving the last integral. I am just wondering if the $\theta_1$ is equal to $arcsin(\frac{(R-r)*sin(\beta)}{R})$ or not ?

Comment: @EsiVaz: given $\sin\varphi=-1$, then $\theta_1$ is a solution of $\frac{\cos\theta_1-\cos\theta_0}{\sin\theta_1}\tan\beta=1$.